# First Column header is fixed if fully scrolled

Tags: css

I have this problem that if I scroll down, the first column header is fixed only if the it is fully scrolled, but if not, the header next column value is visible, please see screenshot for what I meant.

And the code below:

```
<style lang="scss">
.sales-total{
.ui-dialog-graph-table{
    tbody > tr:last-child {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .ui-table-header-cell:first-child{
        background: #dbb100;
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 1000;

    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child{
        background-color:#ddd;
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child{
        background-color:#fff;
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
}
}
```

First row is already fixed for this one.
[image: fully scrolled]
[image: half scroll]

Comment: You want to make the header row fixed... So you can check this code this may help you it is quite easy to understand https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Comment: @SakshiGarg Not the header only, but also the first column should be fixed if scrolled right. I've tried commenting `tbody` and scroll right is not working. I have a hint that there's some attributes in the body that affects the behaviour of the header.

Comment: Ok. got it, just removed the z-index.